# according root permission to www-data

Tags: perl, root

I have a perl script `dhcpmanip.pl` which contain this line:

```
system "hostapd /etc/hostapd-1.0/hostapd/hostapd.conf"`
```

It's a command to start `hostapd` and I get this error :

```
Insecure `$ENV{PATH}` while running setuid at `/var/www/cgi-bin/dhcpmanip.pl` line 46
```

After searching on the net I realised that I should accord root permission to www-data user (apache user) then I tried to modify the file `/etc/sudoers` by inserting this line:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/cgi-bin/dhcpmanip.pl
```

but it still not working...does anyone have any idea about how solving this problem?

Comment: system "sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd-1.0/hostapd/hostapd.conf "

Comment: This isn't a permissions issue, but a check the perl interpreter does (on suid scripts I think) to avoid privilege escalations.

Comment: NB! Granting `ALL=NOPASSWD` privileges to `www-data` is equal as running web services as `root` - this is totally insecure!

Comment: I agree with SaveTheRbtz - **please** don't do that! The internet does not need more cracked webservers.

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz Actually it's only giving permission to run *that one command* with elevated privilege.

Comment: I probably need to elaborate a little on my comment: granting `sudo(1)` to almost any interpretable (shebang'ed) script without restricting environment variables which can manipulate behaviour of interpreter itself (e.g. `PYTHONNOUSERSITE`, `RUBYLIB`, etc) is very dangerous. For native code `sudo(1)` does pretty good job by removing `_RLD*, DYLD_*, LD_*, LDR_*, LIBPATH, etc` from environment.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that message because perl is running in **taint mode**. Either you've set that explicitly (good) or perl turned that on itself because what you're doing is dangerous (bad, but perl is is still doing good).

Either way, perl requires you to sanitize your `PATH` before it will execute external commands.

**You need to explicitly set `$ENV{PATH}` somewhere in your script prior to executing any external commands**.

For good practice you should also explicitly use the *full path* of any external commands you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where hostapd is actually placed, you'd need to set $ENV{PATH} to something. For example, if it was in `/usr/bin` set `$ENV{PATH} = "/usr/bin"` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to be able to go to a particular web page on your computer, and that will make the computer run a script that will manipulate your dhcp setting. As SaveTheRbtz said, this is **not** the secure way to go about it.

When you're running a web server, you want to be sure that any scripts run by the web server have a very limited access to do things on your server. Otherwise, any small mistake in your scripts may lead to some script kiddie getting root on your server and abusing it.

So, if you have a script that needs root access, that script should **not** be run by the webserver user. I would instead use a somewhat more complex setup:

- Create a CGI script that will only write an entry to a file. This requires minimal rights, and done properly (i.e. by overwriting the previous entry instead of adding to it) it will not even risk filling up your disk if someone were to hit it multiple times.
- Create a cron job that regularly checks that file to see if it's been changed. If so, run the script. The cron job can be owned and run by root, thus requiring no extra sudo setup.

This way, the web server user is completely isolated from what the script does that needs root access.